# How to solve unwanted checking of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have been working on a mock-up Menu Register page for a fast-food chain. When I click on a checkbox, the boxes right after the one clicked will be checked while they shouldn't be. I first wondered if the problem has something to do with the jQuery lines, but I figured out it didn't. When the form is separated from the pop-up screen, it functions just fine. Any suggestions?

You can find my HTML code here: https://github.com/riproskaie/menuRegister/blob/main/templates/easierPopup.html

Comment: Provide a sample snippet of the issue rather than a long wall of text. Also you should close your input tags properly.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't pinpoint the snippet that's giving me the issue. I embedded the checkboxes into a pop-up, and the problem seems to occur somewhere in the interconnection between the two. The checkboxes function normally when it's separated from the pop-up template.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're using the incorrect CSS selector. `input:checked ~ label` should be `input:checked + label`. The latter only affects the label directly after the input, while the former affects *every* label after it.

Comment: Now it works just fine! Thanks for the advice :)